# How to select an image from the gallery, re-size it and re-save it to a different gallery folder

Tags: android

I found some code on SO helping me bring up an image selector, save the image, re-size/decode it and display it in an ImageView, however I am wanting to know how to save this newly re-sized image into a different folder in the Gallery and then return it's new location (including the filename) as a String. Here is what I have so far:

Starting the image picker intent:

```
public void openGallery() {
        Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);
    }
```

Getting the selected image:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case SELECT_PHOTO:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                    try {
                        Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                        InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
                        Bitmap yourSelectedImage = decodeUri(selectedImage);
                        imageIcon.setImageBitmap(yourSelectedImage);
                        imageText.setText("");
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        Toast.makeText(this, "Image Selection Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

Function to decode the image:

```
private Bitmap decodeUri(Uri selectedImage) throws FileNotFoundException {

        // Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage), null, o);

        // The new size we want to scale to
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 200;

        // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
        int scale = 1;
        while (true) {
            if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE
                    || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE) {
                break;
            }
            width_tmp /= 2;
            height_tmp /= 2;
            scale *= 2;
        }

        // Decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage), null, o2);

    }
```

I am also unsure whether I have correctly implemented this decode function as changing the REQUIRED_SIZE int makes no difference when it's displayed in the ImageView.

Comment: Compress that resized bitmap in a file output stream targetting a directory at your choice. The gallery app has no folders itself. It is just an app that shows all the pictures on your device.

Comment: @greenapps - If you expand on this as an answer, I will gladly accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this with the below method:

```
public void saveResizedImage(Bitmap image) {

        File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + File.separator + "rapical" + File.separator);
        String path = root.getPath();
        OutputStream fOut = null;
        File noOfImages[] = root.listFiles();
        int fileCount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < noOfImages.length; i++) {
            fileCount++;
        }
        File foodImageFile = new File(path, "rapical" + fileCount + ".png");
        try {
            fOut = new FileOutputStream(foodImageFile);
            image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, fOut);
            fOut.flush();
            fOut.close();
            String imagePath = path + "/rapical" + fileCount + ".png";
            Log.w("ImagePath: ", imagePath);

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
```